# Converting NSString to NSDate is not working

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've read the DateFormatting guide and I'm still not able to get why my date conversion is not working as per requirement.  For example:

```
NSString *str1 = @"12/20/2013 12:39:55 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFo = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFo setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *serverDate1 = [NSDate date];
serverDate1 = [dateFo dateFromString:str1];
```

In return I'm getting date as "**2013-01-05 07:09:55 +0000**".
I have tried a lot why NSDate is not returning correct date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try yyyy instead of YYYY, if still u didnt get, plz revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `YYYY` use `yyyy` in your `dateFormat:`.

```
NSString *str1 = @"12/20/2013 12:39:55 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFo = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFo setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *serverDate1 = [NSDate date];
serverDate1 = [dateFo dateFromString:str1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *dateWithInitialFormat = @"12/20/2013 12:39:55 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFo = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFo setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *serverDate1 = [NSDate date];
serverDate1 = [dateFo dateFromString:dateWithInitialFormat];
```

This will get you your solution